# NSTimer memory management

Tags: ios, nstimer, strong-references

When I execute this code:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(showButtons) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

do I need to nil it or release it, ot whatever for memory management?

I am using ARC

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, `NSTimer` will maintain a strong reference to the `target`, which can cause (especially in repeating timers) strong reference cycles (a.k.a. retain cycles). In your example, though, the timer does not repeat, and is delayed only 0.5, so worst case scenario, you will have a strong reference cycle that will automatically resolve itself in 0.5 seconds.

But a common example of an unresolved strong reference cycle would be to have a `UIViewController` with a `NSTimer` property that repeats, but because the `NSTimer` has a strong reference to the `UIViewController`, the controller will end up being retained.

So, if you're keeping the `NSTimer` as an instance variable, then, yes, you should `invalidate` it, to resolve the strong reference cycle. If you're just calling the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`, but not saving it to an instance variable (as one might infer from your example), then your strong reference cycle will be resolved when the `NSTimer` is complete.

And, by the way, if you're dealing with repeating `NSTimers`, don't try to `invalidate` them in `dealloc` of the owner of the `NSTimer` because the `dealloc` obviously will not be called until the strong reference cycle is resolved. In the case of a `UIViewController`, for example, you might do it in `viewDidDisappear`.

By the way, the [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-1000810) explains what strong reference cycles are. Clearly, this is in a section where they're describing the proper use of weak references, which isn't applicable here (because you have no control over the fact that `NSTimer` uses strong references to the target), but it does explain the concepts of strong reference cycles nicely.

---

If you don't want your `NSTimer` to keep a strong reference to `self`, in macOS 10.12 and iOS 10, or later, you can use the block rendition and then use the `weakSelf` pattern:

```
typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 repeats:false block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
    [weakSelf showButtons];
}];
```

---

By the way, I notice that you're calling `showButtons`. If you're trying to just show some controls on your view, you could eliminate the use of the `NSTimer` altogether and do something like:

```
self.button1.alpha = 0.0;
self.button2.alpha = 0.0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                      delay:0.5
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     self.button1.alpha = 1.0;
                     self.button2.alpha = 1.0;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

This doesn't suffer the retain issues of `NSTimer` objects, and performs both the delay as well as the graceful showing of the button(s) all in one statement. If you're doing additional processing in your `showButtons` method, you can put that in the `completion` block.

Comment: Great answer, but maybe i didn't make clear the fact that I don't actually declere it in the .h file with NSTimer* timer, I just add that code in the .m file, so I cannot invalidate or nil it. In this case is it still ok if I use my timer, or is it better to use the code you provided me?

Comment: @Alessandro I actually presumed you didn't maintain an ivar for the timer. But, obviously, if you want to `invalidate` in `viewWillDisappear`, you'll have to do so. (As an aside, you don't have to put private ivars in your .h; private class extension is better.) And a couple of times you've mentioned about setting a `NSTimer` to `nil`. Please note that this does not resolve strong reference cycle. The timer either needs to either complete (and not be repeating) or you need to `invalidate` (using your new ivar).

Comment: I fully understand that I need to invalidate a timer for it to be removed from the run-loop. After doing such, in terms of re-assigning that property is there any need to set the timer to `nil` and do a `if timer != nil` or that's unnecessary and just doing a `!timer.isValid` is enough? in other words is there any usage to do `timer = nil`? In your previous comment you've already said it has nothing to with memory management so I wonder why a lot of devs keep doing that while `isValid` increases clarity...

Answer (score 2):

If you are saving it in a property, then yes, you do need to set it to nil after it fired the selector.

It's also safe to save it in case your class gets deallocated for whatever reason, so that you can `[timer invalidate]` if you need to.

Comment: If you make that property `weak`, you don't have to `nil` it yourself. It will automatically release itself after it fires (assuming it was non-repeating).

Comment: @Rob Would it be correct to say that: if it was repeating then calling `invalidate` becomes mandatory. Otherwise the run-loop will retain its pointer towards the viewController which is `weak`ly pointing to the timer

Comment: Or, perhaps more accurately, the run loop will keep a strong reference to the repeating _timer._ If the timer is weakly referencing the view controller, the memory impact will be modest, but a timer that is no longer needed will keep firing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use: `myTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(showButtons) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];`
And then in your viewDidDisappear `[myTimer invalidate]`

Answer (score 1):

Use the new method of Timer that uses closures

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: {[weak self] (timer) in
   print("Tick tock")
   guard let ws = self else { return }
   //some action that repeats
   ws.myViewControllerMethod()
})
```