# What is difference between self.timer = nil vs [self.timer invalidate] in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nstimer, strong-references

Can anyone explain me `self.timer=nil` vs `[self.timer invalidate]`?

What exactly happens at the memory location of `self.timer`?

In my code

```
self.timer=nil
```

doesn't stops the timer but

```
[self.timer invalidate]
```

stops the timer.

If you require my code I will update that too.

Comment: [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html) - "Note in particular that run loops maintain strong references to their timers, so you don’t have to maintain your own strong reference to a timer after you have added it to a run loop." So yours isn't the only reference to that timer which is why nil'ing it out isn't preventing it from firing.

Comment: Yup , I got my answer, thnaks

Answer (score 12):

Once you have no need to run timer, invalidate timer object, after that no need to nullify its reference.

This is what Apple documentation says: [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html)

> Once scheduled on a run loop, the timer fires at the specified
>   interval until it is invalidated. A non-repeating timer invalidates
>   itself immediately after it fires. However, for a repeating timer, you
>   must invalidate the timer object yourself by calling its invalidate
>   method. Calling this method requests the removal of the timer from the
>   current run loop; as a result, you should always call the invalidate
>   method from the same thread on which the timer was installed.
>   Invalidating the timer immediately disables it so that it no longer
>   affects the run loop. The run loop then removes the timer (and the
>   strong reference it had to the timer), either just before the
>   invalidate method returns or at some later point. Once invalidated,
>   timer objects cannot be reused.

Comment: After invalidating the timer you should assign nil to the variable otherwise the variable is left pointing to a useless timer.

Comment: Memory management and ARC have nothing to do with why you should set it to `nil`. After invalidating the timer, `self.timer` is now referencing a useless timer. No further attempts should be made to use that value. Setting it to `nil` ensures that any further attempts to access `self.timer` will result in `nil`.

Comment: Rather I would suggest to check self.timer.isValid property in if condition, to before using the same

Comment: @rmaddy very valid point. so regardless of the timer being a repeating or non-repeating when/where should set the timer to `nil`? Should I do it inside the block/selector that the timer fires?

Comment: @Honey Set it to `nil` immediately after invalidating it. If it's not a repeating timer, you can set it to `nil` at the end of the block.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm reading [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer). Not sure if your comments are **now** valid. 1. *A nonrepeating timer invalidates itself immediately after it fires.* So we don't need to invalidate a non-repeating timer at the end of its block 2. *Invalidating the timer immediately disables it so that it no longer affects the run loop. The run loop then removes the timer (and the strong reference it had to the timer)* doesn't that mean it's now `nil`? 3 And doesn't timer like any other property get deallocated once its parent object is deallocated?

Comment: 3. FWIW I created a dummy project and invalidated a timer. It **didn't** get set to `nil`. So I don't understand what *The run loop then removes the timer (and the strong reference it had to the timer)* means. 4. If I don't ever need to reuse/adjust a timer then as long as its parent object is deallocated then all I need to do is `invalidate` it right? `nil`ing is not necessary.

Comment: After some effort I was able to answer my own 4 questions above. I've wrote an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52544614/5175709). Feedbacks are appreciated. @rmaddy

Answer (score 11):

**There is a key difference not mentioned in the other answers.**

To test this, drop the following code in Playground.

### 1st Attempt:

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

class Person{
    var age = 0
    lazy var timer: Timer? = {
        let _timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(fireTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        return _timer
    }()
    
    init(age: Int) {
        self.age = age
    }
    
    @objc func fireTimer(){
        age += 1
        print("age: \(age)")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("person was deallocated")
    }
}

// attempt:
var person : Person? = Person(age: 0)
let _ = person?.timer
person = nil
```

---

So let me ask you a question. At the last line of the code, I just set `person` to `nil`. That means the `person` object is deallocated and all its properties are set to `nil` and removed from memory. Right?

An object is deallocated as long as no other object is holding a strong a reference to it. In our case the `timer` is still holding a *strong* reference to person, because the [run-loop has a strong reference to the timer<sup>§</sup>](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000807-SW6) hence the `person` object will not get deallocated.

The result of the above code is that it still continues to execute!
Let's fix it.

---

### 2nd Attempt:

Let's set the timer to `nil`. This should remove the strong reference of `timer` pointing to `person`.

```
var person : Person? = Person(age: 0)
let _ = person?.timer
person?.timer = nil
person = nil
```

WRONG! We only removed *our* pointer to the `timer`. Yet the result of the above code is just like our initial attempt. It still continues to execute...because the **run loop** is still targeting/referencing `self`.

---

**So what do we need to do?**

Glad you asked. We must `invalidate` the timer!

### 3rd Attempt:

```
var person : Person? = Person(age: 0)
let _ = person?.timer

person?.timer = nil
person?.timer?.invalidate()
person = nil
```

This looks better, but it's still wrong. Can you guess why?

I'll give you a hint. See code below .

---

### 4th Attempt (correct)

```
var person : Person? = Person(age: 0)
let _ = person?.timer

person?.timer?.invalidate()
person?.timer = nil
person = nil
// person was deallocated
```

Our 4th attempt was just like our 3rd attempt, just that the *sequence* of code was different.

`person?.timer?.invalidate()` removes the **run loop's**  strong reference
to its target, i.e. `self`, and now if a pointer to `person` is removed...our person object gets deallocated!

The attempt below is also correct:

### 5th Attempt (correct)

```
var person : Person? = Person(age: 0)
let _ = person?.timer

person?.timer?.invalidate()
person = nil
// person was deallocated
```

Notice that in our 5th attempt we didn't set the timer to `nil`. But Apple recommends that we do such:

> Once invalidated, timer objects cannot be reused.
>
> <sub>See [Task Management - Timer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer)</sub>

Setting it to `nil` is also an *indicator* that for other parts of code. It helps up so that we can check against it and if it wasn't `nil` then we'd know the timer is still valid and also to not have a meaningless object around.

> After invalidating the timer you should assign `nil` to the variable
> otherwise the variable is left pointing to a useless timer. Memory
> management and ARC have nothing to do with why you should set it to
> `nil`. After invalidating the timer, `self.timer` is now referencing a
> **useless** timer. No further attempts should be made to use that value. Setting it to `nil` ensures that any further attempts to access
> self.timer will result in `nil`

> <sub>from rmaddy's comment [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416896/what-is-diffrence-between-self-timer-nil-vs-self-timer-invalidate-in-ios/52544614#comment43277552_27416962)</sub>

That being said I think `isValid` is a more meaningful approach just as `isEmpty` is more meaningful and efficient than doing `array.count == 0`...

---

## So why is 3rd attempt not correct?

Because we need a pointer to the timer so we can invalidate it. If we set that pointer to `nil` then we loose our pointer to it. We lose it *while* the **run-loop** has still maintained its pointer to it! So if we ever wanted to turn off the timer we should `invalidate` it **BEFORE** we lose our reference to it (ie before we set its pointer to `nil`) otherwise it becomes an abandoned memory ([not leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840168/whats-the-difference-between-abandoned-memory-and-a-memory-leak)).

## Conclusion:

- To get stop a timer correctly you must use `invalidate`. Do not `nil` the `timer` before you `invalidate` it.
- After you've invalidated a `timer`, set it to `nil` so it doesn't get reused.
- Calling `invalidate` will remove the run loop's pointer to `self`. Only then the object containing the timer will be released.

---

**So how does this apply when I'm actually building an application?**

<s>If your viewController has `person` property and then your popped this viewController off your navigation stack then your viewController will get deallocated. In its `deinit` method you must invalidate the person's timer. Otherwise your person instance is kept in memory because of the **run loop** and its timer action will still want to execute! This can lead to a crash!</s>

**Correction:**

Thanks to [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534654/nstimer-memory-management/13534780#13534780)

*If you're dealing with repeating [NS]Timers, don't try to invalidate them in dealloc of the owner of the [NS]Timer because the dealloc obviously will not be called until the strong reference cycle is resolved. In the case of a UIViewController, for example, you might do it in viewDidDisappear*

That being said `viewDidDisappear` may not always be the correct place since `viewDidDisappear` also gets called if you just push a new viewController on top of it. You should basically do it from a point that it's no longer needed. You get the idea...

---

> §: Because the run loop maintains the timer, from the perspective of
> object lifetimes there’s typically no need to keep a reference to a
> timer *after you’ve scheduled it*. (Because the timer is passed as an
> argument when you specify its method as a selector, you can invalidate
> a repeating timer when appropriate within that method.) In many
> situations, however, you also want the option of invalidating the
> timer—perhaps even before it starts. In this case, you *do* need to
> keep a reference to the timer, so that you can stop it whenever
> appropriate.

---

<sub>With all the credit going to my colleague Brandon:</sub>

## Pro Tip:

Even if you don't have a repeating timer, the Runloop [as mentioned within the docs] will hold a strong reference to your target if you use the [selector function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer), until it fires, after that it will release it.

However if you use the [block based function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/2091889-scheduledtimer) then as long as you point weakly to self inside your block then the runloop will not retain `self`. However it will continue to execute, due to the lack of calling `invalidate`

If you don't use `[weak self]` then the block based will act just like the selector kind, that it will deallocate `self` after it has been fired.

Paste the following code in Playground and see the difference. The selector version will be deallocated **after** it fires. The block base will be deallocated **upon** deallocation. Basically the lifecycle of one is governed by the runloop while for the other it's governed by the object itself

```
@objc class MyClass: NSObject {
    var timer: Timer?
    
    func startSelectorTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(MyClass.doThing), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    
    func startBlockTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: false, block: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.doThing()
        })
    }
    
    @objc func doThing() {
        print("Ran timer")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("My Class deinited")
    }
}

var mySelectorClass: MyClass? = MyClass()
mySelectorClass?.startSelectorTimer()
mySelectorClass = nil // Notice that MyClass.deinit is not called until after Ran Timer happens
print("Should have deinited Selector timer here")

RunLoop.current.run(until: Date().addingTimeInterval(7))

print("---- NEW TEST ----")

var myBlockClass: MyClass? = MyClass()
myBlockClass?.startBlockTimer()
myBlockClass = nil // Notice that MyClass.deinit IS called before the timer finishes. No need for invalidation
print("Should have deinited Block timer here")

RunLoop.current.run(until: Date().addingTimeInterval(7))
```

Comment: Thanks for this in-depth analysis. I came here because I was wondering if it's necessary to set a timer to `nil` after invalidating it. Apple docs seem to suggest that this is not necessary. But in my own testing, I found that just invalidating a timer doesn't delete that instance of the timer from memory. It's good to see that you reached that same conclusion. So I guess that it's good practice to always set a timer to `nil` after you invalidate it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `invalidate` is a method of `NSTimer` class which can use to stop currently running timer. Where when you assign `nil` to any object then, in an ARC environment the variable will release the object.

Its important to stop running timer when you don't longer need, so we write `[timer invalidate]` and then we write `timer = nil;` to make sure it'll loose its address from memory and later time you can recreate the timer.