# Using invalidate in NSTimer in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

Suppose if i create an NSTimer with the code. The code calls a function which dismisses view controller after 90 second

- A) Is it necessary to InValidate NSTimer every time when that view
  controller dismisses?
- B) What is the use of invalidate? And when to
  use invalidate ?
- C) If i don't use invalidate will it cause any side
  effects like Memory Leak? (edited)

Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already, I would encourage you to review the [documentation for `NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer), as two of your three questions are answered clearly there (emphasis below mine):

---

> A) Is it necessary to InValidate NSTimer every time when that view controller dismisses?

> ### Comparing Repeating and Nonrepeating Timers
>
> You specify whether a timer is repeating or nonrepeating at creation time. **A nonrepeating timer fires once and then invalidates itself automatically**, thereby preventing the timer from firing again. By contrast, a repeating timer fires and then reschedules itself on the same run loop [...]

---

> B) What is the use of invalidate? And when to use invalidate ?

> #### Stopping a Timer
>
> - [`invalidate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer/1415405-invalidate)
>
>   Stops the timer from ever firing again and requests its removal from its run loop.

---

> C) If i don't use invalidate will it cause any side effects like Memory Leak? (edited)

The documentation linked above does not explicity speak to this particular aspect of using `NSTimer`, but a simple search yielded a particularly helpful [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534654/nstimer-memory-management) regarding `NSTimer`-related memory management. I've included the most relevant content from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13534780/269970) below:

> Yes, `NSTimer` will maintain a strong reference to the `target`, which can cause (especially in repeating timers) strong reference cycles (a.k.a. retain cycles). In your example, though, the timer does not repeat, and is delayed only 0.5, so worst case scenario, you will have a strong reference cycle that will automatically resolve itself in 0.5 seconds.
>
> But a common example of an unresolved strong reference cycle would be
> to have a `UIViewController` with a `NSTimer` property that repeats,
> but because the `NSTimer` has a strong reference to the
> `UIViewController`, the controller will end up being retained.
>
> So, if you're keeping the `NSTimer` as an instance variable, then,
> yes, you should `invalidate` it, to resolve the strong reference
> cycle. If you're just calling the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`,
> but not saving it to an instance variable (as one might infer from
> your example), then your strong reference cycle will be resolved when
> the `NSTimer` is complete.